# How to avoid React fetch API replacing url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch-api

I've made a POST request with the react Fetch API, it works as desired, except for the fact that it replaces the url of the current page.

Post Function:

```
  postNote(note) {
    console.log('Posting note');

    fetch('http://localhost:9000/notes/create', {
      mode: 'cors',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(note)
    })
  }
```

When this function execute, it replace my url with:

> http://localhost:3000/?name=nameExample&description=descExample

I don't know why this happens, as i used this API before, and i didn't have this problem. If anyone can give me any help, i would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance, have a great week!

Edit 1:

I create the note object like this:

> const newNote = {id: 0, name: note.name, description: note.description, author_id: note.author_id, author: note.author };

Edit 2:

The postNote function is triggered by this function:

```
addNote = note => {
        const newNote = {id: 0, name: note.name, description: note.description, author_id: note.author_id, author: note.author };
        this.setState({
            notas: [...this.state.notas, newNote]
        });
        console.log(newNote);

        this.postNote(newNote);
    }
```

Edit 3:

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => {
      let newNote = { id: 0, name: this.name, description: this.description, author_id: this.author_id, author: this.author }
      noteContainer.addNote(newNote)
      }
 }>
      Save
</button>
```

Comment: Is there a proxy in package.json?

Comment: I don't see how this is possible. Is the URL hardcoded, or is it populated from a variable of some sort. I'd console.log that variable, and make sure it's intended for port 9000.

Comment: You need to show more of the code involved. The fetch by itself is not going to cause the URL of the current page to be changed. How is the fetch being triggered?

Comment: No @stever  it's not!

Comment: @FrankerZ ,it's not hardcoded, the only part that i populate from a variable is the body, i edited the question to add how the note object is created.

Comment: @RyanCogswell i added the function that triggers the postNote function

Comment: I'm using unstated to manage the state of my app, just in case it has somethin to do!

Comment: @RohrFacu What triggers addNote? What user action triggers this?

Comment: Is this triggered by a `<form>` submit?  Are you preventing the default?

Comment: It is triggered by a onClick function on a  <button>, that is inside a <form> i edited the question again!

Comment: @zero298 , i wasn't preventing the default. Add your answer, it works! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<button>`s within `<form>`s trigger `submit` events.  If you don't prevent that `submit` event from triggering the default action using `event.preventDefault()`, the form will do it's normal action; posting the form data to whatever URL you specified as the `action` of the `<form>`.

Since you are trying to override the normal functionality and submit the data your own way, tell the `<form>` not to do it's normal action.

```js
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // If the e.preventDefault() weren't there,
  // you would navigate to some.html on the Stack Snippets host
  // (it doens't exist so you actually get a 404 or something

  console.log("Hello");
});

document.getElementById("bar").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Same thing here, except we prevent the click
  // event from triggering the submit event higher up

  console.log("World");
});
```

```html
<form id="foo" action="some.html">
  <button>Click Me</button>
</form>

<form action="some.html">
  <button id="bar">Click Me 2</button>
</form>
```